# Why C# append get on property in class written in VB.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

If we make any class in VB.NET and try to access its property in C# by making object of that class. get_ is appended in the property. Can any one please explain the reason.

Comment: Please give an example of both the C# and VB code. If you're genuinely accessing a property, you shouldn't see the get_ part in the C# code. If you were calling a property as if it were a method, you would see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh it may be because the whole:

- `get{}`
- `set{}`

business actually translates into the equivalent of:

- `get_PropertyName`
- `set_PropertyName`

In the IL code.
The whole property stuff we write (in either `VB` or `C#`) is just syntactic sugar.